# Almost vertically middle aligned

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="plaisio">
   <div id="phone">
     <img src="img/phone.png" >
   </div>  
   <div id="phone_num">
     <img src="img/phone_num.png" >
   </div>
 </div>
```

and its responding CSS:

```
.plaisio{
overflow: auto;
max-width:320px;
line-height:100px;
margin-top: 25px;
background-color: #333333;
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #000000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #000000);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #000000);   
}
.plaisio img{
vertical-align:middle;
}
#phone{
float:left;
    width:20%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:8%;
}
#phone_num{ 
float: left;
width:65%;
margin-right:2%;
}
```

You may see it live at http://users.sch.gr/ellhn. Look  the phone image and the number at the footer. My query is why the two pictures(phone.png and phone_num.png) are almost and not exactly  vertically aligned. If you examine the page thoroughly, you 'll find that the two pictures are nearest to the bottom of .plaisio and not at the middle as someone should expect!

Thank you

Comment: #phone & #phone_num are floatting. your image have nothing but themselves to vertical-align to since they stand alone in their container. your code behaves as it should

Comment: Why you put a phone number as an img? o.O

Answer (score 1):

dispay  `inline-block` `#phone` and `#phone_num` , **no** `float` and `vertical-align` them to each other.

You may set image , as `display :block` or `vertical-align:top` or `bottom` to erase the gap left under *(gap used by letters j,q,p,y,)*.